# Failed loading ZendOptimizer.so: invalid ELF header

Tags: centos5, zend-optimizer

How do you solve `Failed loading ZendOptimizer.so: invalid ELF header` on CentOS 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Linux version of `ZendOptimizer.so`.
http://secure.diverge.com/blog/note/invalid-elf-header/

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer "accepted" when you are able.